# Don't know where to start...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Should I count it by hand, or there is a general mechanism?

Let N be the largest positive integer with the following property: reading from left to right, each pair of consecutive pair of consecutive digits of N forms a perfect square. What are the leftmost three digits of N?

Comment: Hehe. *Pairs of consecutive pairs of consecutive* is linguistically a pair of consecutive *pairs of consecutive*'s. Lewis Carroll would have liked that.

Comment: How does this problem has to do with Lewis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call a number with such a property a **good** number.

We consider all $2$ digit squares: $16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81$. From this, the only $3$ digit **good** numbers are are $164, 364, 649, 816$.

For $4$ digit **good** numbers, we observe the last digit of each $3$ digit **good** number and the first digit of each $2$ digit squares. The possibilities are $1649, 3649, 8164$.

Similarly, for $5$ digit **good** numbers, we observe the last digit of each $4$ digit **good** number and the first digit of each $2$ digit squares. The only possibility is $81649$. This is the value of $N$ required.

Comment: Are u sure this the largest value? Prove it

Comment: I believe that the construction of all possibilities is itself an implicit proof.

Comment: From what Yiyuan wrote, you can be see there are no **good** numbers with more than 5 digits. There is only one **good** number with 5 digits, and this must be the largest **good** number, because a 5-digit number is larger than any number with fewer digits. If you were to allow two-digit squares beginning with zero, such as $09$, you should observe that there are no **good** numbers bigger than $09$ containing any $0$s. This is because the only digit that could be to the left of a $0$ is another $0$, there being no perfect squares in the set $\{10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90\}$.